# Designs review session with engineering teams

Tags: review, backlog, meeting

I would love to get feedback or advice around the organisation of a weekly or biweekly design focused session to run with members of various teams.

The purposed of this 30 minutes session is to review outstanding and new questions that might be linked to undefined designs (or new ones needed).

Our design team works on an agency based level meaning that we can't afford to have a single design in each squad. This session would support tracking existing design related questions and give the possibility to the teams to have a forum where new questions can be raised.

Has any of you dealt with a similar scenario?
Do you have any advice on how to approach this design focused session with engineering teams?

Comment: You are assuming that these design review sessions will solve the problem of dealing with outstanding and new questions that come up from undefined designs. Shouldn't there already be a process in place for defining the requirements for specific project and product features? Keep in mind the addition time and cost required to organize these meetings, and whether there are simpler solutions.